# Erro ao tentar deserializar JSON vindo de uma página web

Tags: c#, .net, json, chatbot, luis

Estou utilizando o Luis.ai para criar minha rede neural de intents e o Microsoft Bot Framework para criar meu chatbot, mas não estou conseguindo ler um json que o luis está gerando para mim.

Classe do luis:

```
public static async Task<LuisResult> GetResponse(string message)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var url = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/06145033-fb92-485e-acd5-0bf432e892d5?subscription-key=a66048dcba8e4dcd845c91ebfff5a031&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=-180&q=" + message;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return null;
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        var js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LuisResult));

        return (LuisResult)js.ReadObject(result);
    }
}
```

Como eu estou o chamando:

```
Console.WriteLine(luis.GetResponse(activity.Text.ToLower()).Result.Intents[0].Intent.ToString());
```

Estou fazendo tudo de maneira local.

**EDIT:**

Quando eu faço a depuração, ele fica infinitamente nesta linha:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

Eu criei outra solução, fiz todo o processo de baixar o Json, e nessa solução nova funcionou perfeitamente...

Comment: Você pode trocar para a bibiloteca NewtonSoft.Json?

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas como ficaria o código? @Tiago

Comment: Mudanças minimas

Comment: Até então você não tem erro algum, são 2 warnings. O primeiro, sobre o debug de System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll e a opção de debug "just my code". O segundo warning fala do repasse do token JWT, no entanto a mensagem é apenas um warning de que não está repassando o token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei exatamente qual é o problema, mas consegui consertar utilizando a seguinte linha de código:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

Talvez depois eu pesquise mais sobre isso e volte para falar o porque o erro estava ocorrendo.

Comment: Eu também não sei o motivo disso, mas já passei por isso e resolvi da mesma forma. Talvez pudesse virar uma pergunta, o que você acha?

Comment: @TiagoS Acho proveniente. Cria ai que eu deixo meu +1.

Answer (score 4):

**Importante** Você precisa pegar o pacote NewtonSoft.Json no [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Você troca estas linhas do código

```
var js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LuisResult));

return (LuisResult)js.ReadObject(result);
```

para

```
var js=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LuisResult>(result);
```

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
public static async Task<LuisResult> GetResponse(string message)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var url = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/06145033-fb92-485e-acd5-0bf432e892d5?subscription-key=a66048dcba8e4dcd845c91ebfff5a031&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=-180&q=" + message;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return null;
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LuisResult>(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta, da uma olhada.